# empty set inside lapply in R

Tags: r, lapply

Ia m using R, v. 3.3.2.. I am trying to parse some html documents. I have following function:

```
relation <- function(html_files){
    zk_files <- htmlParse(html_files, encoding = "UTF-8")
    kopija <- xpathSApply(doc = zk_files, path = "/html/body/table/tr[3]/td[3]/span", fun = xmlValue)
    zemlja <- xpathSApply(doc = zk_files, path = "/html/body/table/tr[4]/td[2]/span", fun = xmlValue)
    sud <- xpathSApply(doc = zk_files, path = "/html/body/table/tr[6]/td[2]/span", fun = xmlValue)
    odjel <- xpathSApply(doc = zk_files, path = "/html/body/table/tr[7]/td[2]/span", fun = xmlValue)
    y <- as.data.frame(odjel); colnames(y) <- "odjel"
    odjel_2 <- merge(x = y, y = zk_odjeli[,c(2,3)], by.x = "odjel", by.y = "Zk_Odjel", all == FALSE)
    stanje <- xpathSApply(doc = zk_files, path = "/html/body/table/tr[8]/td[2]/span", fun = xmlValue)
    opcina <- xpathSApply(doc = zk_files, path = "/html/body/table/tr[10]/td[2]/span", fun = xmlValue)
    opcina <- as.numeric(gsub(pattern = "[^0-9]", replacement = "\\1", x = opcina))
    ulozak <- xpathSApply(doc = zk_files, path = "/html/body/table/tr[10]/td[3]/span", fun = xmlValue)
    ulozak <- as.numeric(gsub(pattern = "[^0-9]", replacement = "\\1", x = ulozak))
    broj_dnevnika <- xpathSApply(doc = zk_files, path = "/html/body/table/tr[12]/td[2]/span", fun = xmlValue)
    tip_vlasnistva <- xpathSApply(doc = zk_files, path = "/html/body/table/tr[12]/td[3]/span", fun = xmlValue)
    tip_vlasnistva <- if (length(tip_vlasnistva)==0) {NA}else{returntip_vlasnistva}
    plombe <- xpathSApply(doc = zk_files, path = "/html/body/table/tr[13]/td[2]/span", fun = xmlValue)
    tip_izvatka <- xpathSApply(doc = zk_files, path = "/html/body/table/tr[14]/td[2]/span", fun = xmlValue)
    id <- paste0(odjel_2[,2], "-",opcina, "-",ulozak)
    final_list <- list(kopija, zemlja, odjel, sud, stanje, opcina, ulozak, broj_dnevnika, plombe, 
                       tip_vlasnistva, id)
}
```

Then I use lapply function to apply this functio on html files:

```
lapply(files, relation)
```

My output looks like this:

```
structure(list(Html = list(c("NESLUŽBENA KOPIJA", "NESLUŽBENA KOPIJA", 
"NESLUŽBENA KOPIJA"), c("REPUBLIKA HRVATSKA", "REPUBLIKA HRVATSKA", 
"REPUBLIKA HRVATSKA"), c("POSEBNI ZEMLJIŠNOKNJIŽNI ODJEL U KLANJCU", 
"POSEBNI ZEMLJIŠNOKNJIŽNI ODJEL U KLANJCU", "POSEBNI ZEMLJIŠNOKNJIŽNI ODJEL U KLANJCU"
), c("Općinski sud u Zlataru", "Općinski sud u Zlataru", "Općinski sud u Zlataru"
), c("Stanje na dan: 09.05.2016. 23:24", "Stanje na dan: 09.05.2016. 23:24", 
"Stanje na dan: 09.05.2016. 23:24"), c(313637, 313637, 313637
), c(8, 16, 21), c("Broj zadnjeg dnevnika: Z-1001/2014", "Broj zadnjeg dnevnika: Z-633/2011", 
"Broj zadnjeg dnevnika: Z-274/2012"), c("Aktivne plombe: ", "Aktivne plombe: ", 
"Aktivne plombe: "), NA, c("112-313637-8", "112-313637-16", "112-313637-21"
))), .Names = "Html")
```

The problem is in part

```
tip_vlasnistva <- xpathSApply(doc = zk_files, path = "/html/body/table/tr[12]/td[3]/span", fun = xmlValue)
tip_vlasnistva <- if (length(tip_vlasnistva)==0) {NA}else{tip_vlasnistva}
```

**I have an empty set (`logical(0)`), which I convert to `NA`, but in the output I don't get `NA`'s n times, but only one times you can see in the output. How to handle empty set (logical(0)) i lapply to get the same dimension as with other variables?**

Comment: maybe something like `tip_vlasnistva <- if (length(tip_vlasnistva)==0) {rep(NA, unique(sapply(output_list, length)))}else{tip_vlasnistva}`

Comment: what should I put instead `output_list`?

Answer (score 0):

The have somehow found the answer: I have just use paste0() function inside:

```
tip_vlasnistva <- paste0(xpathSApply(doc = zk_files, path = "/html/body/table/tr[12]/td[3]", fun = xmlValue))
```

It makes it "" instead of logical zero, which lead to wanted output.